# Custom URL for Google Sites for Free

Tags: google-sites

Hi is it possible to customize the Google site?

Instead of  https://sites.google.com/view/brandname

I want to make it like this https://sites.google.com/blog/brandname

is it possible to remove the * view/

**Sorry for the wrong grammar

Thank you in advance, Hoping someone knows this.

I tried to search through Google but had no luck.